# CGAffineTransformConCat/ CGAffineTransformMakeScale in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, cgaffinetransform

I'm trying to update a part of a function for swift 3:

```
  let newLabelOffset = CGFloat(direction.rawValue) * originalFrame.size.height/2

    newLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformConCat(
      CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,0)
      CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,newLabelOffset)
    )
```

I've heard that the new way of using `CGAffineTransformConCat` is `concatenating(_:)` but not entirely sure how to set it up based on the 2 above transforms.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Init transforms,

```
let trans1 = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0, y: 0)
let trans2 = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0,y: 1)
```

Concatenate,

```
trans1.concatenating(trans2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In swift, Function is overloadable. All matrix transform which contains translation, scale, rotate implemented by function `CGAffineTransform()` using different parameters.

```
init(rotationAngle: CGFloat)  // rotate
init(scaleX: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) // scale
init(translationX: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) // translation
func concatenating(CGAffineTransform) -> CGAffineTransform // matrix multiplication
```

Even, you can totally define transform matrix by using `init(a: CGFloat, b: CGFloat, c: CGFloat, d: CGFloat, tx: CGFloat, ty: CGFloat)`, the construct of matrix is:

[image]

More: [Apple developer documentation of CGAffineTransform](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgaffinetransform)